# Joins in Hibernate Criteria query language by primary and foreign key Relation

Tags: hibernate, join

I want to fetch records from three tables which are related as follows:

**Book.java** Book.java {Bid,name,authorid //set and get }

**Author.java** {Aid,aName,age //set and get}

**Company.java** {cId,bookId,Cname//set and get}

these are the classes and properties in POJO

So i want to fetch `Bid,Aid,aName,Cname` from all these tables with `Hibernate` Criteria query language, please help me in this i am new TO hcql.

**Note:** there is only primary key and foreign key relation between these tables and no one to one or one to many

Comment: You can't if you don't have `@ManyToOne` between your entities. In your Book entity you must have a `@ManyToOne` with the Author and not a String authorid

Comment: ok thank you , is it possible with hql atleast? with the same format

Answer (score 0):

with Hql you can do something like this :

```
select book.Bid, author.Aid, author.aName, company.Cname from Book book,Author author,Company company where
book.authorid=author.Aid and book.Bid=company.bookId
```

Comment: if suppose i dont know the relation between these two tables, then how can i do the same in hql ,, like i am getting input in the below format                                                                                                            Book_Bid,Book_authorid,Company_Cid,Author_Aid,Author_aName  and this input may vary each time i need to parse the input and do some string operations and i can implement in query

Comment: this query is hql. If you don't know the relation I dont see the point doing such a query, just remove the where condition and you will get a cross join with no meaning